# Practical method to do MLE for natural parameters in exponential family

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, optimization, normalization, exponential-family

*I encountered the following question in my research and I hope this is the correct place to post it. I'm following the notation in [this lecture note](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter8.pdf) by Michael I. Jordan.*

Assume random vector $X$ follows some exponential family distribution:

$$p(X=x|\eta)=\exp(\eta^T T(x)-A(\eta))f(x),$$

where $\eta$ is the vector of natural parameters and $T(x)$ is the vector of sufficient statistics.  As an exponential family, it can also be parametrized by the mean parameter vector:

$$\mu = \mathbb{E}_{p(x|\eta)}[T(X)] = \frac{\partial A}{\partial \eta^T}(\eta).$$

Let $\mathbf{x}_n = (x_1,...,x_n)$ be a data vector composed of i.i.d. samples from this distribution.  I would like to do maximum likelihood estimation for the parameter $\eta$.  It can be shown that the MLE of the mean parameter is:

$$\hat{\mu}_{ML} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n T(x_i),$$

so mathematically we have:

$$\hat{\eta}_{ML} = \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial \eta^T}\right)^{-1}(\hat{\mu}_{ML}).$$

However, in practice, usually  $A(\eta)$ is only given by the normalization condition $\int p(x|\eta) dx = 1$ and it is not explicitly known.  $A(\eta)$ itself is also hard to evaluate numerically because $X$ may be of high dimension.  In view of this, I'm wondering in this case how should we get the value of $\hat{\eta}_{ML}$?

Answer (score 3):

In most (standard) exponential families, the moment generating function $A)\eta)$ is available in closed form. Here is a [screen-copy from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Table_of_distributions) that shows the beginning of a list of examples, each of which can be easily inverted:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The distribution I encountered doesn't fall into those standard exponential family distributions. Actually here the $X$ is of very high dimension, and I'm pretty confident that the closed-form expression for $A(\eta)$ is not known.

Comment: I then suggest you include your problem in the question itself.

Comment: It's a statistical mechanics problem and its details are not very related to this question. Also I think this question itself is also valid in a broader context. The only background information I want to borrow from the original problem are 1. $X$ is of high dimension and 2. the closed-form of $A(\eta)$ is not available.